# How to delete mdb date type data in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm writing a program employees check IN/OUT simple system. But I can delete other type data except `Date` type.

How can I delete it?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
DELETE FROM [INOUT] 
WHERE [TIMEDATE] = '4/4/2016 12:12:12 PM';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround your date with `#` and not `'`, and `format()` your date as **MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss** which is Access standard

```
DELETE FROM [INOUT] 
WHERE [TIMEDATE] = #04/04/2016 12:12:12#
```

Comment: @miurangadilshan glad it worked, but then mark my answer as answered please